# What is the total number of graphs where it has no edges between odd numbered and no edges between even numbered vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

My question states that -

> **Let A represent a graph with vertex set V = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}.  Suppose graph A has no edges between odd-numbered vertices and no
> edges between even-numbered vertices.  How many such graphs are
> there?**

I know that the maximum number of edges a graph with N vertices can contain is X = N * (N – 1)/2 and that the total number of graphs that can be formed with n vertices will be is XC0 + XC1 + XC2 + … + XCX = 2^(X).

I do not know how to apply the condition of odd and even numbered vertices in the problem and how to find out the total number of such graphs. Any help with understanding the logic will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you list all the edges having one end at $1$ are permitted by the odd/even criteria?  ... having one end at $2$?  Can you list all the edges that are permitted?  (There aren't that many.)

Comment: @EricTowers the edges permitted by the criteria with one end at 1 would be {(1,2),(1,4),(1,6)}. the edges permitted by the criteria with one end at 2 would be {(2,1),(2,3),(2,5)}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are bipartite graphs. If you have a bipartite graph on $X$ and $Y$, each $x \in X$ you can have edges to a subset of $Y$, i.e., $2^{\lvert Y \rvert}$ possibilities. This you need to multiply for each edge:

$\begin{align*}
  \prod_{x \in X} 2^{\lvert Y \rvert}
    &= 2^{\lvert X \rvert \cdot \lvert Y \rvert}
\end{align*}$

In your case, if you have the numbers $\{1, 2, \dotsc, n\}$, there are $\lfloor n / 2 \rfloor$ even ones and $\lceil n / 2 \rceil$ odd ones, for a total of:

$\begin{align*}
   2^{\lfloor n / 2 \rfloor \cdot \lceil n / 2 \rceil}
     \sim 2^{n^2 / 4}
\end{align*}$

Comment: That makes sense to me. Thank you for answering.